# How can I filter incoming webhook messages in Slack?

Tags: slack

I have several Slack integrations built using [incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) but some of them are pretty noisy. With any kind of incoming webhook I set up, it seems like there are two things I always want to do.

- Apply a rate limit to messages sent through the webhook
- Temporarily mute messages through the webhook using filters

I guess I'm looking for a webhook proxy that can filter whether messages are allowed through the webhook, and optionally re-route them if certain criteria are met. Does Slack have this capability natively? Or are there any bots or premade integrations that can do this?

Comment: I'd be glad if I could just temporarily hide all Webhook messages from the channel.